# Como posso fazer com que um programa abra um arquivo salvo no computador sem que, para isso, este programa esteja sendo executado?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Olá! Gostaria de compartilhar uma dúvida que estou tendo em um programa que ando desenvolvendo do tipo Windows Application em linguagem C#. Trata-se de um bloco de notas para meu uso pessoal.

O funcionamento dessa aplicação é o mesmo do bloco de notas padrão, ou seja, o usuário digita um texto e pode salvar um arquivo com esse texto. Para não haver confusão com outros arquivos de texto, o programa salva numa extensão definida como *.tst . Além do botão de salvar e salvar como, existe o botão de abrir, que abre uma caixa de dialogo para que o usuário escolha um arquivo .tst a ser exibido ou editado no próprio programa.

No entanto, não consigo implementar para que usuário, ao clicar em um arquivo .tst salvo no seu pc, execute o programa já com as informações desse arquivo carregadas na caixa de texto (como ocorre com os arquivos em outras extensões que podem ser abertos com seus aplicativos padrões).

O método System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() retorna o caminho do diretório do arquivo que executou o programa. Acredito que ele possa ser usado para que a aplicação possa realizar o que foi falado.

A seguir, apresento o código utilizado pela aplicação. Também, anexei uma imagem do formulário da aplicação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BlocoDeNotas
{
public partial class frmBNote : Form
{
string caminhoAbrir, caminhoSalvar; //string com o caminho do arquivo para salvamento e do arquivo que deve ser aberto
string caminhoSalvarCopia; //salva uma cópia do caminho para salvamento do arquivo

```
    public frmBNote()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmBNote_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string caminhoArq = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); //caminho do arquivo (.tst ou .exe) que executou a aplicação
        string caminhoExe = Application.StartupPath; //caminho do executável da aplicação
    }

    void Salvar() //método para salvar o texto inserido pelo usuário na TextBox
    {
        SaveFileDialog caixaSalvar = new SaveFileDialog();

        caixaSalvar.Filter = "(*.tst) | *.tst"; //extensão dos arquivos de texto criados no programa
        caixaSalvar.DefaultExt = "tst"; //definição dessa extensão

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(caminhoSalvar))
        {
            caixaSalvar.ShowDialog();
            caminhoSalvar = caixaSalvar.FileName;
            caixaSalvar.Dispose();

            try
            {
                File.WriteAllText(caminhoSalvar, TxtJanela.Text, Encoding.Default);
                this.Text = "B-NOTES - " + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(caminhoSalvar);
                MessageBox.Show("Arquivo salvo!");
            }
            catch
            {
                caminhoSalvar = caminhoSalvarCopia;
                MessageBox.Show("O arquivo não foi salvo.", "ATENÇÃO!");
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            File.WriteAllText(caminhoSalvar, TxtJanela.Text, Encoding.Default);

            MessageBox.Show("Salvo!");
        }
    }

    private void SalvarClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Salvar();
    }

    private void salvarComoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        caminhoSalvarCopia = caminhoSalvar;
        caminhoSalvar = null;

        Salvar();
    }

    void Abrir() //método para abrir na TextBox o texto salvo no arquivo escolhido pelo usuário
    {
        OpenFileDialog caixaAbrir = new OpenFileDialog();

        caixaAbrir.Filter = "(*.tst) | *.tst";
        caixaAbrir.DefaultExt = "tst";

        caixaAbrir.ShowDialog();
        caminhoAbrir = caixaAbrir.FileName;
        caixaAbrir.Dispose();

        try
        {
            TxtJanela.Text = File.ReadAllText(caminhoAbrir, Encoding.Default);
            this.Text = "B-NOTES - " + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(caminhoAbrir);
            caminhoSalvar = caminhoAbrir;
        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    private void abrirToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Deseja salvar o arquivo atual?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Salvar();
            Abrir();
        }
        else
        {
            Abrir();
        }
    }

    private void novoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Deseja salvar o arquivo atual?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Salvar();
            TxtJanela.Text = "";
            this.Text = "B-NOTES";
            caminhoAbrir = caminhoSalvar = caminhoSalvarCopia = null;
        }
        else
        {
            TxtJanela.Text = "";
            this.Text = "B-NOTES";
            caminhoAbrir = caminhoSalvar = caminhoSalvarCopia = null;
        }
    }

    private void frmBNote_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Deseja salvar o arquivo atual?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Salvar();
        }
    }

    private void sairToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Eu acho que isso vai te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924753/where-does-windows-store-its-open-with-settings

Comment: Eu achei outra parecida: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788429/c-sharp-windows-open-with-context-menu-behaviour

Comment: Você tem que criar a associação da extensão com o seu programa (adicionar entradas de registro), O Sistema operacional chamara seu programa com o arquivo como argumento, No seu Main virá um parâmetro que é o arquivo a ser aberto. Numa pesquisa básica você encontra tudo isso no google. Outro ponto, se quer que abra sempre na mesma janela terá que implementar uma lógica de SINGLETON (Single Instance ou instância única), e enviar uma mensagem para o programa já aberto com o caminho do arquivo.

Comment: Mas se você não precisa distribuir isso para clientes é mais fácil, pressione com o botão direito no arquivo, selecione abrir com... clique em pesquisar e encontre seu programa, se não abrir de primeira é por que seu programa não trata o argumento enviado pelo sistema operacional no Main(string[] args) <= args contém o arquivo a ser aberto. Você pode selecionar "Sempre usar esse aplicativo..." para criar a associação permanente.

Comment: Muito obrigado, pessoal! Consegui aqui. Modifiquei o método Main() para Main(string[] args) e deu super certo com alguns ajustes.